# Subversion externals problem

Tags: svn, externals

I am new to SVN and make heavy use of the externals property.  I have a repository located on my PC and the externals properties have a hardcoded 'localhost' in the name, which is now giving me problems.  For example:

```
/project1/trunk
/shared/trunk
```

`project1/trunk` depends on the shared folder so has an `svn:externals` property of **svn://localhost/shared/trunk**.  This works fine with TortoiseSVN and I can checkout `project1/trunk` and am given a copy of `shared/trunk`.

Now I have moved the repository to another server and the externals links no longer work for obvious reasons (TortoiseSVN is trying to checkout out `svn://localhost/shared/trunk` which no longer exists).

So I need to update all my externals - but I don't want to hardcode any machine names - so how do I make this work?  Bear in mind that the repository may move again at some point.  Digging around the SVN manuals I came across the **^/** syntax, so I tried the following:

```
svn:externals shared ^/shared/trunk
```

This was accepted but when I try and checkout a copy of `project1` on my PC I get the following error:

```
Unrecognized format for the relative external URL 'shared'.
Check the path and/or URL you've entered.
```

Unless I hardcode the repository machine name in the externals I can't make this work - it seems like a black art so any advice would be welcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ^/ syntax you refer to is new in SVN 1.5, so you may be using an older version of the client and/or server that doesn't understand that syntax.  Also, in order to support the new externals syntax in 1.5, they changed the order of the paramters in the externals definition.  I think you want the path first, then the folder name for it to appear under.  The details are in the [docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals).